# Add indicator to required form field

Tags: javascript, extjs

in ExtJs 4.0.2 for requred field indication, i'm using this code:

```
Ext.override(Ext.layout.Layout, {
  renderItem: function(item, target, position) {
  if (item && item.isFieldLabelable && !item.rendered && item.fieldLabel &&   item.allowBlank == false) {
     item.fieldLabel += ' <span class="req" style="color:red">*</span>';
   }
  this.callOverridden(arguments);
 }
 });
```

But in ExtJs 4.1 this code, don't work. What is changed? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No,i don't getting errors, but in Extjs 4.02 argument item is all objects on layout, including all fields of form. In Extjs 4.07 i'm getting only one object is the ext.grid. Although, i have one grid, one form and two component on north and west region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout new label markup changes in 4.1.x http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-afterLabelTextTpl You don't need your override anymore.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I'm made so: in defaults property of form: `defaults: {afterLabelTextTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl if="allowBlank === false"><span style="color:red;">*</span></tpl>', { disableFormats: true })}`